# A polynomial time complexity algorithm for the BoxDepth problem

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

> BoxDepth Problem:
>
> Given $n$ rectangles, such that their sides are parralel to the
>   coordinate axes ($x$ and $y$), Find a subset with maximum size such
>   that the intersection of its members are not empty.

---

Question:

Provide a polynomial time algorithm for BoxDepth problem.

Note 1: The algorithm doesn't have to be optimal. The only thing that matters is the time complexity.

---

Note 2: I was thinking of taking each $2$ rectangles and check if their intersection is empty. But, that takes more than polynomial time. Is there a better algorithm that i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Suppose that you know what the final intersection is, can you find all the rectangles that belong to your set?
- Intersection of two rectangles is a rectangle, so your final intersection is a rectangle too.
- The coordinate for the left side of the intersection rectangle is a coordinate for the left side of *some* rectangle in your set (and also for right, top, bottom, only each might be a different rectangle from your set).
- If you want the intersection to be non-empty, just pick a left-top side of your intersection and ensure that all your rectangles contain it.
- If you have $n$ rectangles, you have $n$ possibilities for the left side and $n$ for top, so with plain enumeration of all rectangles that would give you complexity $O(n^3)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$